# Split a string at second occurence of Comma

Tags: python, arrays, string

My string is like below:

```
Str=S1('amm','string'),S2('amm_sec','string'),S3('amm_','string')
```

How can I Split the string so that my str_list item becomes:

```
Str_List[0]=S1('amm','string')
Str_List[1]=S2('amm_sec','string') 
...
```

If I use `Str.split(',')` then the output is:

```
Str_List[0]=S1('amm'
...
```

Comment: Please format your code, as it stands, it is unreadable. Also, you are almost surely talking about *python lists* not *python arrays*.

Comment: your strings should be in quotes. as-is, this will try to apply `S1` as a function, and give a syntax error even if it is defined.

Comment: Where does this string come from? Is it possible for the inner strings like `'amm'` to contain quotes or commas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex with `re` in python

```
import re
Str = "S1('amm','string'),S2('amm_sec','string'),S3('amm_','string')"
lst = re.findall("S\d\(.*?\)", Str)
```

this will give you:

```
["S1('amm','string')", "S2('amm_sec','string')", "S3('amm_','string')"]
```

to explain the regex a little more:

`S` first you match 'S'

`\d` next look for a digit

`\(` then the '(' character

`.*?` with any number of characters in the middle (but match as few as you can)

`\)` followed by the last ')' character

you can play with the regex a little more [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=98312)

Comment: I would suggest replacing `S\d` with `\w+` to be more general.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to replace `',S'` with `' S'` using regex and split on spaces.

```
import re
Str = re.sub(',S',' S',Str)
Str_list = Str.split()
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for taking a look and to help with Answers. I am able to split now. But now getting another issue :

Comment: Hi..Thanks for taking a look and to help with Answers. I am able to split now. But now getting another issue :
SCHEMA = ["SchemaField('amm_reporting_row','string')", "SchemaField('amm_section','string')", "SchemaField('amm_report_row_desc','string')", "SchemaField('amm_subsection_row','float')", "SchemaField('amm_subsection
_desc','string')"]
and SCHEMA[0] gives me SCHEMA[0] = SchemaField('amm_reporting_row','string') and so on
but i need array without double quotes and each element of Array in new line.

If double quotes can be removed then it will be correct.

Comment: is SchemaField a function? do you want a list of function calls?

Comment: yes..SchemaField is a function imported from "from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField "  I need to Create Table dynamically and format is:

Comment: `for command in Str_List: exec(command)` will run each string as a function